# In Github, how do you determine which branch the release came from

Tags: github

I am managing a repo and I want to know which branch releases are created from.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Releases are created from the branch you select when creating the release:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You decide from what branch to release

https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository